# c# convert string YYYYMMDDTTTTTT to datetime

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a string date into a format for sql datetime.

The format is like:
"20140428132222"
I think this equates to
YYYYMMDDTTTTTT

Comment: Did you even try to search for this before posting a question?

Comment: this works for me like a charm as well `var timestamp = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss.fff}", DateTime.Now);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
 DateTime dt;
 bool valid = DateTime.TryParseExact("20140428132222", "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

gives `4/28/2014 1:22:22 PM`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DateTime.ParseExact(string, string, IFormatProvider)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It's helpful to **Read the Documentation**:

- [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [System.DateTime Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

  In particular, look at the methods

  - [`DateTime.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
  - [`DateTime.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
  - [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
  - [`DateTime.TryParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The various [constructor overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can also be useful. You pick out the various bits, convert them to integer values and use the constructor.